# RcppModules: Manually build/expose C+ classes to R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

The goal is to wrap fairly large existing collection of C++ classes to be callable from R. The first approach is to manually define R Reference Classes and call into "SEXP-wrapped" entry points - and this works fine, no problems. Another approach that I'm currently evaluating is RcppModules. I can successfully use it with toy example **within R** - with `Rcpp::SourceCPP`. But have troubles with doing this manually. Example:

```
//---example.cpp

#include "Rcpp.h"

using namespace Rcpp;

class Example
{
  public:
    Example(){};

    SEXP add(SEXP x_, SEXP y_) const
    {
      double x = as<double>(x_);
      double y = as<double>(y_);

      double res = x + y;
      return wrap(res);
    }
};

RCPP_MODULE(Example_Module) {
  class_<Example>( "Example" )
  .constructor()
  .method( "add", &Example::add )
  ;
}
```

Then build/compile:

```
g++ "-I...\\R\\win-library\\3.2\\Rcpp\\include" "-I...\\R\\R-3.2.2\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o example.o "..\\example.cpp" 
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -lR -shared "-L...\\R\\R-3.2.2\\bin\\x64" -o example.dll example.o -lR
```

which produces `example.dll` with no warnings/errors...

Then, following the commands of `Rcpp::SourceCPP` (with `verbose = TRUE`), loading the dll and populating the environment:

```
`.example` <- dyn.load('example.dll')

library(Rcpp)
populate( Rcpp::Module("Example_Module",`.example`), environment() )
```

The last call to `populate` crashes R (within RStudio).

As I understand, additional to the binary, Rcpp must create R code containing generated R class, which is then loaded to environment. Is there a way to see this code? 
Is it possible (is it suitable) to use RcppModules from outside of R for wrapping large number of C++ classes? 
And the last question is that existing C++ code is obviously split in header files containing class declarations and source files containing class method implementations. Can RcppModules be applied in this case? - all examples I have seen are in a single cpp file.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this manually?

Comment: Because I have large library of existing C++ classes. I don't see how I can expose to R and compile ~100 files within R...

Comment: Hmm I guess I'm not really clear on what you are asking.

Comment: The general question is how to use RcppModules to expose wrappers ~100 C++ classes which declaration/implementation is placed in .h/.cpp files

Comment: Well hopefully you are proficient in some type of scripting language because most likely you are going to have to rewrite some code. I don't see how doing this for 100 classes is any different than doing it for one, just that you have to do it 100 times.`RCPP_MODULE` is just a convenience macro that generates the necessary boilerplate code for exposing a C++ class to R. If you are looking for a bulk processing equivalent then unfortunately I don't believe such a thing exists.

Comment: automating stuff is not a problem. my questions include: 1) can one use `RCPP_MODULE` from within c++ header files; 2) can it be done without SourceCpp; 3) how can one see generated by Rcpp code for R classes ... etc.. I don't see how compiling and populating single CPP file from R with SourceCpp extends to real C++ library containing many classes within header/source files. Say I have exact same `Example` class as above declared in header file with implementations in source files - how would I use Rcpp in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @nrussell for engaging you in some clarification here.  Your last comment has a few more specific questions I'll answer briefly:

1) Well yes, `RCPP_MODULE` is always used in a header file.  See various examples packages on CRAN and maybe use [r-pkg.org](http://www.r-pkg.org) to search.

2) Yes. Use a package. See dozens of answers here suggesting a package.  DO NOT DO IT BY HAND. Do not write Makefiles manually.  Use a package.

3) No canned answer for that.

Look around and study e.g. Rich FitzJohn's [RcppR6](https://github.com/richfitz/RcppR6) which *expressively written for the use case of many local classes* where Rcpp Modules became too slow at load.

Several of my packages use Rcpp Modules, but these are comparatively small packages.

For extended discussion, subscribe to and post on the rcpp-devel list.

Comment: Dirk - thanks for your comments. just to make sure -in 1) you mean in source (cpp) file? - never seen a single example when `RCPP_MODULE` within header file.. For 3) should I take it as "close-to-no"? - I can't see the generated classes?  Of course I'll try to investigate this more and go to the mailing list.. I've also looked at the documentation for RCPP_MODULES+packages - it's really brief... Not very clear how to start approaching large existing code with all tht

Comment: Ah, yes, cpp file for `RCPP_MODULE`.

Comment: I finally settled with writing "glue" functions using `Rcpp::XPtr` smart pointer and other types, then developing `R6` classes by hand. It's all been working pretty well for me. Thanks