# Rcpp module error with a constructor taking NumericVector& as parameter

Tags: rcpp

I have a problem with constructor that looks like 
**MyModel::MyModel(const Rcpp::NumericVector& ModelData)** in the code below.

It gives a new error on my **new mac version (clang7 with R 3.6.0)** gives **no error with windows**, and **no error with older (<=3.0.? ) version of R on mac**.

I guess I'm doing something wrong that only gave a warning before and that is now an error. Anyone could help ? (I posted this on the Rcpp mailing list) 
Below are the code and the error.

```
code='
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
class MyModel{  public: MyModel(const Rcpp::NumericVector& ModelData) {};};
RCPP_MODULE(MyModel){
    Rcpp::class_<MyModel>(\"MyModel\")
    .constructor<const Rcpp::NumericVector &>()
    ;
}'

sourceCpp(code=code)
```

> In file included from file5a40416569b1.cpp:2:
>   In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
>   In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:168:
>   In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:25:
>       /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h:31:30: error: reference member 't' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object
>                           Exporter( SEXP x ) : t(x){}
>                                                  ^
>       
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:87:41: note: in instantiation of member function 'Rcpp::traits::Exporter &>::Exporter' requested here
>                   ::Rcpp::traits::Exporter exporter(x);
>                                               ^
>       
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:152:26: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::internal::as &>' requested here
>               return internal::as(x, typename traits::r_type_traits::r_category());
>                                ^
>       
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_Constructor.h:47:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::as &>' requested here
>               return new Class( as(args[0]) ) ;
>                                 ^
>      
>  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_class_constructor.h:99:29: note: in instantiation of member function 'Rcpp::Constructor_1 &>::get_new' requested here
>               AddConstructor( new Constructor_1 , valid, docstring ) ;
>                                   ^
>       file5a40416569b1.cpp:7:6: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::class_::constructor &>' requested here
>           .constructor()
>            ^
>       
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h:35:9: note: reference member declared here
>                           T t ;
>                             ^
>      
>  1 error generated.
>       make: *** [file5a40416569b1.o] Error 1
>       /usr/local/clang7/bin/clang++  -Wall -
> I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -
> I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -
> I"/private/var/folders/zt/7cz1y9md79l_h08bbqymt4w9z8xlw7/T/RtmpZZ6sit/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-1.0.1" -isysroot 
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -
> I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c file5a40416569b1.cpp -o file5a40416569b1.o
>       
> Error in sourceCpp(code = code) : 
>         
> Error 1 occurred building shared library.

Comment: Are you really sure this ever worked with `sourceCpp()`?  Modules are somewhat special -- I would use a package as per [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090458/rcppmodules-manually-build-expose-c-classes-to-r).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes I am sure. It is a very simple piece of code I created from a package I have written and that has worked fine for years. This started to go wrong last week after an automatic update of my mac that lead to an update of R... In addition, it works fine now on windows with R3.5.3 (and gives no warnings).

Comment: FWIW it fails for me on Ubuntu 18.10 with `g++ 8.3` so it isn't just `clang`.  And as my earlier post shows, what you did may never have been or documented or supported use case. So ... I would still write a package.  YMMV.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks. But what do you mean when you say "I would still write a package" ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Interesting; it compiled fine for me using `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` on Ubuntu 18.10 with g++ 8.3.0,  R 3.6.0, and Rcpp 1.0.1. Robin, I think Dirk means that rolling your code into a package would be preferable to compiling as stand alone code. I was able to successfully compile your code on my machine in an R package by creating a package structure using the R command `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("modEx", path = "/tmp", example_code = FALSE)`, then saving your code in a file `/tmp/modEx/src/MyModel.cpp`, then running the R command `devtools::install("/tmp/modEx/")`

Comment: @duckmayr thanks ! I also have this code in a package but it was not convenient to show the code here within a package and since the error remains the same I choose not to mention the package.

Comment: There is something else going on. It works for me _if I switch to `inline::cxxfunction`_ but not as posted via `sourceCpp()`.

Comment: No error for me with R 3.6.0 and g++ 6.3.0 on Debian (stable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just fixed that in follow-up discussion on the rcpp-devel list where a [minimally complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was presented -- it wastes everybody's time not to supply one was done here initially.

In short, we cannot do `&` for reference semantics with the `SEXP` pointer to S Expression objects.  Simply removing the `&` fixes it.  Corrected code below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class MyModel {
public:
  double a;
  ~MyModel();
  MyModel();
  MyModel(const Rcpp::NumericVector ModelData, int temp);
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(MyModel)

MyModel::~MyModel() {}
MyModel::MyModel() : a(0) {}
MyModel::MyModel(const Rcpp::NumericVector ModelData, int temp) : a(0) {}

RCPP_MODULE(MyModel) {
  Rcpp::class_<MyModel>("MyModel")
  .constructor()
  .constructor<const Rcpp::NumericVector, int>()
  ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I don't understand what you mean by "it wastes everybody's time not to supply one was done here initially." The example provided in my question is more minimal and still a complete example. It was posted afterward.

Comment: I was mostly mad (possibly at myself) that I couldn't build / reproduce with the example here. It worked with the one you posted on the list; I think this one is incomplete.  And we didn't yet know we needed to switch compilers too.